# MySQL, PHP and named pipes on Linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am to the point.

I put the following in `MySQL` configuration file:

```
[mysqld]<br/>
enable-named-pipe<br/>
skip-networking<br/>
```

But, now, How to connect to `mysql` from `php` using named pipes in Linux? Can you gives me a `connect.php` example?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_enable-named-pipe

> Enable support for named pipes. This option applies only on Windows.

Connect to `localhost`.

Comment: There is some alternative for linux without a tcp connection?

Comment: Mysql creates a unix socket by default, and connections to localhost [by name] use that socket [if it exists] instead of the network, and I don't know why *actual* localhost would be a problem.

Comment: @Sammitch socket  or named pipe is faster that is why he asked

Comment: @M.AliEl-Sayed Connecting to `localhost` *is* the local socket thanks to some kludgery in the mysql drivers, `127.0.0.1` is the only way to connect to TCP localhost.